# How can I check with an If Else query, if a method found something in the database or not?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

How can I write an If Else query to check if something was found in the database or not?

For example in my program a person gets extra money for a certain month,

Now I need to check with an If Else query, if the method that gets the month and money from the database, got a month or nothing at all

```
datareader = Class.Month(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
datareader.Read();
int Money = dr.GetInt32(0);
```

Currently at `int Money= dr.GetInt32(0);` I get an error that we found nothing, but that's what I'd like to fix. If nothing is found then I want to set `int Money` to the number 0

Comment: What do you have so far? Please include a [mcve].

Comment: I am pretty sure nobody knows, what you're going to achieve, with the information you currently provided.

Comment: _"but if i have nothing i get an error,"_ - what error do you get

Comment: i get an error that he finds nothing in the database, but thats it! if he finds nothing i want the int Money= dr.GetInt32(0); to get the number 0 , i tried int Money= dr.GetInt32(0) + 0 ; but that doesnt work

Comment: Please let us no the exact error - saying _"i get an error that he finds nothing in the database"_ does not help us help you at all. If you get an exception, then edit your question with the text of that error.

Comment: I get the error "No data for that row/column" , can i somehow check if the datareader.Read returns something or not?

Comment: @LarNani did you read documentation ... Read is `void Read()` or `bool Read()` ? ... seriously ... you should start with documentation instead asking

Comment: what documentation? im only a few months in programming & dont know what ure asking for

Comment: Okay got it, it was "dr.HasRows" ,  but this side is pure garbage wannabe computerscienentists that do it for 10 years already think theyre kings instead of just providing an answer they need to critic everything i write crying that i didnt wirte the error when it was not even the question

Comment: Official documentation of IDataReader class which can be found on learn.microsoft.com `Advances the IDataReader to the next record.
public bool Read ();
Returns
Boolean
true if there are more rows; otherwise, false` Your Laziness ... more over ... when you are using VS(not code) the docs appear with code completion

Comment: _"critic everything i write crying that i didnt wirte the error when it was not even the question"_ - without having access to your application & database we can only guess at any issues you may be having. One of the things that helps us help you is having full information about any errors you may be getting. We are not criticising anything you write, just trying to get the information we need to help you - the alternative would be to look at what you have written, decide there isn't enough information to answer & then just ignore the question.

Answer (score 0):

one of solution is make try-catch in C# code [by tag]

also you could make at first select count(*) ... and if it get 0 react as you want

Answer (score 0):

Try to check before getting value that row is returned or not
like

```
SqlDataReader datareader = Class.Month(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());

try
{
    if (datareader.Read()) // It will only checks the value if row returned
    {
       int Money= dr.GetInt32(0); 
    }
    else
    {
       // No data in datareader
    }
}
catch (Exception exc) //If any run-time error occurs it would be handled
{
    // exc.Message // contains the error message if error happens
}
```